# tikzpicture overlap an other using longtable and wrapfigure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, box, overlap

Good morning!

I 'm trying to:

- have a pgfplot inside a longtable,
- wrap the text (inside the table's cell) around this tikzpicture,
- have a theorem below the longtable,
- have the theorem inside a box.

The problem is that the plot and the theorem's box are overlapping, as you can see.

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{||lp{0.7\textwidth}}
    text1 text1 text1 & text2 text2 text2 text2\\
text1 text1 text1 & text2 text2 text2 text2
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
    unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    grid,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    xmin=-3.5,
    xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-5.5,
    ymax=5.5]
    \addplot [smooth,ultra thick,domain=-2:2] {2*x};
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-2,-4)} ;
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(2,4)} ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{itemize}
    \item text $f(x)=2x$,
    \item text $[\alpha,\beta]=[-2,2]$ text
    \item text $x_0=2$,
\end{itemize} 
text text\\
 \end{longtable}


\tikzstyle{BoxTheo2} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{TitlTheo} =[fill=white, text=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [BoxTheo2] (boxtheo){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}

text theo text theo

    \end{minipage}
};
\node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{theorem}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank's in advansed!!!

**EDIT**

I have thought of a solution, but I don't like it. I only post it for the completeness of the answers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}


\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{||lp{0.7\textwidth}}
        text1 text1 text1 & text2 text2 text2 text2\\
        text1 text1 text1 & text2 text2 text2 text2

            \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
            \begin{axis}[
            unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
            width=0.5\textwidth,
            grid,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
            ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            xlabel style={below right},
            ylabel style={above left},
            xmin=-3.5,
            xmax=3.5,
            ymin=-5.5,
            ymax=5.5]
            \addplot [smooth,ultra thick,domain=-2:2] {2*x};
            \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-2,-4)} ;
            \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(2,4)} ;
            \end{axis}
            \node at (-4,4) {\begin{minipage}{0.3\textheight}
                \begin{itemize}
                \item text $f(x)=2x$,
                \item text $[\alpha,\beta]=[-2,2]$ text
                \item text $x_0=2$,
                \end{itemize}
                \end{minipage}};
            \end{tikzpicture}


        text text\\
    \end{longtable}


    \tikzstyle{BoxTheo2} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
    \tikzstyle{TitlTheo} =[fill=white, text=black]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [BoxTheo2] (boxtheo){%
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}

        text theo text theo

        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{theorem}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is using `minipage` instead of `wrapfigure` an option?

Comment: Since your figure is overlayed, LaTeX (or longtable) has no idea that it is even there.  One option is to add extra space (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456074/text-after-tcolorbox-overlapping-with-figure-inside-wrapfig/456632?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#456632).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of wrapfigure, this solution puts the itemize and the figure into a tabular together.  It seems to work better to do all the calculations outside the longtable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots,wrapfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{longtable} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{% neasure width
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \begin{axis}[
    unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
    width=0.5\textwidth,
    grid,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xtick={-3,-2,...,3},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    xmin=-3.5,
    xmax=3.5,
    ymin=-5.5,
    ymax=5.5]
    \addplot [smooth,ultra thick,domain=-2:2] {2*x};
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(-2,-4)} ;
    \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(2,4)} ;
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\setlength{\tempdima}{\dimexpr 0.7\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-\wd\tempbox}%
\begin{longtable}{||lp{0.7\textwidth}}
    text1 text1 text1 & text2 text2 text2 text2\\
text1 text1 text1 & text2 text2 text2 text2 \\
&\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\tempdima}r@{}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item text $f(x)=2x$,
    \item text $[\alpha,\beta]=[-2,2]$ text
    \item text $x_0=2$,
\end{itemize} & \raisebox{-\height}{\usebox{\tempbox}}% align tops
\end{tabular}\\
text text\\
 \end{longtable}


\tikzstyle{BoxTheo2} = [draw=black, fill=white, very thick,
rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{TitlTheo} =[fill=white, text=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [BoxTheo2] (boxtheo){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}

text theo text theo

    \end{minipage}
};
\node[TitlTheo] at (boxtheo.north) {\textbf{theorem}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: demo]

```
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found a solution like yours: I put the itemize as a node of tikzpicture. I think both solutions have the same result. How do you evaluate this solution?

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  BTW, you can submit your own solution and even accept it a couple of days later (i.e. use the check symbol).